# Java FileOutputStream: path relative to program folder?

Tags: java, file, path, fileoutputstream

What is the best way to find a path relative to the folder where a java application is "installed"?

I have a class with a static method: `public static void saveToFile(String fileName)`

When I call it with an absolute path, it works, but what I really want is the relative path to where the application is run from, and a folder.

I have not deployed my application, but right now I want to find a path relative to the (Netbeans) project root, and a folder within called data: **ProjectName\data\file.dat**. Should I use the `File` class or make it into a `URI` or something?

Note that I prefer it to be system-independent and will still work if the application is deployed. Eventually the (relative) pathname will be stored in a **properties** file.

Sorry if this question is a duplicate, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best way to find a path relative to the folder where a java application is "installed"?

OS manufacturers have been saying for a long time **not to** save files in the application directory.

> Note that I prefer it to be system-independent and will still work if the application is deployed.

Instead put the `File` in a `sub-directory` of `user.home`.  User home is where it should be possible to establish a file object that can be read or written.  It is also a place that is reproducible across runs, and platform independent.

Answer (score 2):

If you deploying as a jar, its possible to obtain the jar file name and path the current code is working in like this:

```
new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

(from [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file))

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Answer (score 1):

To find relative path to current working directory say `new File(".")`.

If you want to know absolute path of current working directory you can write `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()` or File(".").getAbsoluteFile()`.

I hope this answers your question. I am sorry if I did not understand you correctly.

Comment: You didn't understand correctly. He wants the program path, not the working directory.

Comment: I tried by using `"." + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + "file.dat"` And it didn't work...

Comment: Allright I tried it with a File and I printed the absolute path, its **absolutely correct** and it didn't work... It returns `C:\blah\projectName\data\file.dat`as required...

Comment: use File("./filename") . It comes to ../workspace/myWorkingProject/filename

Answer (score 0):

To get the absolute path to a file use new File().getCanonicalFile().

```
new FileOutputStream(new File(".\\target\\dataset.xml").getCanonicalFile())
```